# uibarbuttonitem highlight tint/color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

can we change the color/tint of a uibarbuttonitem when it is selected and it highlights? The app i am creating will be be used out doors often and would like it to be more noticeable in high glare situations for the user to know that he actually pressed the button.

EDIT: i would like to change the color for the button's highlighted state

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but you could try subclassing `UIBarButtonItem` and then overriding the `touchesEnded:withEvent:` and `touchesBegan:withEvent:` methods and then using them to set the `tintColor` for your `UIBarButtonItem` instance.

You'd add this to your `UIBarButtonItem` subclass:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

Comment: possible, but wouldn't touchesEnded end when the user lifts his finger off the screen and thus reverting back to original color? where as i am looking to keep the new color until the code has executed. this could work as a fall back, to at least better show that the user did press the button.

Comment: ...OK so in that case just omit `touchesEnded:withEvent:` from my example...?

Comment: i suppose at the end of the method i could reset the tintColor to normal... i'll give it a try, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass UIBarButtonItem and put UIButton inside of it with different background images colours for different states.

```
- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = (CGRect){CGPointZero, image.size};

    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIImage *highlightedImage = [image imageWithColor:[UIColor textHighlightColor]];
    [button setBackgroundImage:highlightedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [button setBackgroundImage:highlightedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [button addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    self = [self initWithCustomView:button];

    return self;

}
```

You need to put this into UIImage category:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color
{

    // begin a new image context, to draw our colored image onto
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size);

    // get a reference to that context we created
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);

    // translate/flip the graphics context (for transforming from CG* coords to UI* coords
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    // set the blend mode to color burn, and the original image
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeMultiply);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, self.CGImage);

    // set a mask that matches the shape of the image, then draw (color burn) a colored rectangle
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.CGImage);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
    CGContextDrawPath(context,kCGPathFill);

    // generate a new UIImage from the graphics context we drew onto
    UIImage *coloredImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //return the color-burned image

    return coloredImg;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

A UIButton is a subclass of UIControl which has an adjustsImageWhenHighlighted, an showsTouchWhenHighlighted and a showsTouchWhenHighlighted property.

A UIBarButtonItem is a subclass of UIBarItem and has none of these. It does however have a UIBarButtonItemStyle which when set to UIBarButtonItemStylePlain which says for the button to glow when tapped (but you can't specify the color).